# Mongodb c# 2.0 driver , how to find and find or how to where and where and all count()

Tags: c#, mongodb

in mongodb C# 2.0 Driver

```
    ···   var lists = base.Collection.Aggregate();

        if (cId > 0)
        {
            lists = lists.Match(n => n.cId == cId);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spell))
        {
            lists = lists.Match(n => n.Spell == spell || n.Name == spell);
        }
        //  var count = lists.count();
      var results = lists.ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

···

yes,it's work ,

but i want know lists all `count()` , to   `Skip()` and `Limit()`

in mongodb 1.x Driver

```
var lists = base.collection.AsQueryable().where(n => n.cId == cId).where(n => n.Spell == spell || n.Name == spell))；

var count = lists.count();
var result = lists.skip(10).limit(20).tolist();
```

my question:

if Match is right .how get Matchs result all `count()`,if use Match is not Perfect way, how to write this code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

get all count from collection

```
IMongoCollection<T>.CountAsync(new BsonDocument()).Result
```

specify where statement for count

```
var filter = Builders<Trailer>.Filter.Eq("YourFieldName", "match value");
IMongoCollection<T>.CountAsync(filter).Result;
```

get all collection and use skip and limit

```
IMongoCollection<T>.Find(new BsonDocument()).Skip(skip).Limit(limit)
                .ToListAsync().Result;
```